# NLP extract dictionary words from sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

I have used Standford NLP for identify POS of a given sentence.

I need to extract only proper words ( words defined in dictionary) from a sentence.

For eg: If the sentence is " *I went to New York in Flight 6AWDR* "

When I use standford NLP , both the words "*flight*" and "*6AWDR*" are marked as "NNP"  by the PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class.

How can I extract proper english words alone in a sentence ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Apache Utils to identify if the string isAlpha.

Assumption is that most of alphanumeric words will be not valid words in dictionary ( unless they are abbreviations )